# Delphi Application Error with Ole in a DLL

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-7, comobject

I have a Com Object, setup/create/working from a DataModule.

creating/running/freeing the Datamodule from an Application works with out an issue.

but putting the datamodule into a DLL works fine the first time, runing the com object etc.. but after a few calls with out restarting the application, this error appears.

[Error Message image http://darkaxi0m.name/so/errormessage.GIF](http://darkaxi0m.name/so/errormessage.GIF)

There is a fare bit of code in the App, so i cant post it all, 
I have tried MadExcept in both the Application and Dll, with no luck. The IDE Breaks at a point that does not seem much help...

[alt text http://darkaxi0m.name/so/cpubreak.gif](http://darkaxi0m.name/so/cpubreak.gif)

this is the code that handles the DataModule, the same function is used in the Application and the Dll in both tests

```
function GetAmount( Amount : integer; var Info: PChar): integer; stdcall;
 var
  tempInfo: string;
   workerDM : TworkerDM;
 begin
  Result := 0;    
  workerDM := TworkerDM.Create(nil);
    try      
      tempInfo:= Info;
      Result := workerDM.GetAmount(Amount, tempInfo);
      StrPCopy(Info, tempInfo);
    finally
      workerDM.Free;
    end;
 end;
```

i would like to blame the Ole Object, but it works fine out of the Dll

I'm at a loss to even think where to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this question can be answered any more.
The project has be scraped, and the object that produce the error no longer used.

My *Delete* Requests have gone unanswered.

So this is now my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the `finally`, you are calling `Free`, but should call `workerDM.Free`.

Comment: sorry that was a victim to copy/pasting and formatting for stackoverflow

Comment: @Christopher: no problem; I have bumped into a lot of real world code that was wrong that way, causing very hard to find bugs. Nice that your code did not suffer from it.